# How to play FLV video at "incoming frames speed" (not video-internal) coming from NetStream in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, red5, netstream

**How to play NetStream frames immediatly as they arrive without any additional AS framerate logic?**

I have recorded some audio & video data packets from `RTMP` protocol received by Red5, and now I'm trying to send it back to the flash client in a loop by pushing packets to `NetStream` with incrementing timestamp. The looped sequence has length of about ~20 sec nad is build from about ~200 RTMP packets (VideoData/AudioData)

Environment: both Flash client and server on localhost, no network bottleneck, video is H.264 encoded earlier by same Flash client.

It generaly works, but video is not very fluent - there ale lot of freezes, slowdowns and long pauses. **The slower packets transmitting causing the more pauses and freezes.**, even extreme long pauses like transmiting whole sequence 2x-3x times (~60 sec) without effect - this comes up when forwarding slower than ~2 RTPM packets per second.

**The problem looks like some AS-logic is trying to force framerate of a video, not just output received frames**, so one of my questions is **does AS looks for in-video-frame fps info in live streaming?** why it can play faster, but can't play slower? How can I play video "by frames" not synchronizing video fps with RTPM packets timestamps?

On the other side, if I push packets faster than recorder, the video is just faster but almost fluent - I just can't get slower or stable stream (still very irregular speed).

I have analysed some `NetStream` values:

- `.bufferLength` = ~0 or 0.001, incrasing when I forward packets
  extremaly fast (like targeting ~90fps)
- `.currentFPS` = shows real FPS
  count seen in `Video` object, not incoming frames/s
- `.info.currentBytesPerSecond` = ~8 kB/s to ~50kB/s depending on
  forwarding speed
- `.info.droppedFrames` = **frequently incrases, even if I
  stream packets like 2/sec!** also jumps after long self-initiated-pause (but buffer
  is whole time 0!)
- `.info.isLive` = true
- `.info.dataBufferLength` = same as `.bufferLength`

It looks like AS is dropping frames, because of too rare RTMP packets receive - like expecting that they will arrive with internal-frame-encoded-fps-speed.

My currently best `NetStream`configuration:

```
chatStream.videoReliable = false;
chatStream.audioReliable = false;
chatStream.backBufferTime = 0;
chatStream.bufferTime =0;
```

Note that if I set `bufferTime` to `1`, video is paused until gathering "1 second of video" but **this is not true** - buffering is very slow, like assuming that video has FPS of 100 or 200 - even if I'm forwarding packets fast (like targeting ~15fps without buffer), the buffer is filing about 10-20 seconds.

Loop, of course, starts with keyframed video data and keyframe interval of sequence is about 15 frames.

Comment: Are you using the NetStream in Data Generation Mode, i.e. feeding it packets with `NetStream.appendBytes()`?

Comment: No, I use `NetStream.play( 'some_stream' , 'live' );

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried netStream.step(1)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#step()

Also I would remove 'live' from the play() call.

Finally, maybe flash tries to sync to the audio like it does in regular timeline. Have you tried a video without audio channel?

Comment: Can't use setp because of live streaming and don't know about incoming frames speed. But +1 for audio suggestion, thanks